# Prove that $a \mid b$ iff $r_i \le s_i$ for every $i$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $a = p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2} \dots p_k^{r_k}$ and $b = p_1^{s_1}p_2^{s_2} \dots p_k^{s_k}$ where $p_i$ are distinct positive primes and $r_i, s_i \ge 0$. Prove that $a \mid b$ iff $r_i \le s_i$ for every $i$.

Suppose $a \mid b$. Then $s_i - r_i$ must be nonnegative, otherwise at least one of the factors of $\frac ab$ will be a fraction whose denominator is not $1$. So, $s_i \ge r_i.$

Suppose every $s_i \ge r_i.$ Then $a \le b$. So, $a \mid b.$

Does the proof work?

Comment: Hint. What you've proved is the opposite of what your title asks for. To do that one you can find the factor $c$ such that $ac=b$ - what must the powers of the primes in $c$ be?  Work out some small numerical examples first if necessary.

Comment: No, you have proved the other direction.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am supposed to be proving it in both directions. I'll fix it.

Comment: He tried proving both sides. The problem with the last sentence is that $a\le b\not\implies a\mid b$. E.g., $2\le 3\not\implies 2\mid 3$.

Comment: @ Ethan Bolker, if $ac = b \to c \le b$, so the if the $t_i$ is one of the powers of $c$, then $t_i \le s_i$?

Comment: The powers of $c$ are of the form $s_i - r_i$?